# A $T_1$ connected space having more than one point.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I want to show that any connected $T_1$ space having more than one point has dimension at least $1$.

Here's my proof:

$X$ is a $T_1$ space i.e if $x,y\in X$ then there exist open nbhds $V_x , V_y$ s.t $x\notin V_y$ and $y\notin V_x$.

Let $\mathcal A := \{ \mathcal{U}_\alpha : \bigcup_\alpha\mathcal{U}_\alpha = X \}$ be an open covering of $X$, then a refinement of it would be: $\mathcal B := \{ \mathcal U_\alpha \cap V_x , \mathcal U_\alpha \cap V_y, V_x ,V_y \}$.

Then since $X$ is connected there exists $\alpha$ s.t $x\in \mathcal U_\alpha \cap V_x$, so we have that every point in $X$ has at least two elements of $\mathcal{B}$ in which it lies in.

Is this right, or do I need to change something in my argument?

Thanks.

Comment: Every set in $\mathcal B$ is contained in $V_x\cup V_y$. Are you sure that $\mathcal B$ is a refinement?

Comment: @ajotatxe Well, I believe that you can find $\mathcal U_\alpha$ in $\mathcal A$ that covers $V_x$ or $V_y$. Not sure how to argue for this though.

Comment: It looks like you misunderstood what you need to show. To show that the dimension is at least $1$, you need to show that there exists an open cover that has no refinement that consists of disjoint sets. For connected spaces, that means there is a cover such that $\{X\}$ is not a refinement.

Comment: @DanielFischer does $\{ V_x ,V_y \}$ is the appropriate cover? I mean we cannot find $U$ in this cover that covers $X$.

Comment: Wrong article, it's _an_ appropriate cover. Show that for any refinement of that cover, there must be a $z\in X$ that is contained in at least two sets of the refinement.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I take some refinement of $\{ V_x , V_y \}$, say $\mathcal B$ then $\forall B\in \mathcal B$ we have either $B\subset V_x$ or $B\subset V_y$; I don't see how to find such $z$, we don't know if $V_x \cap V_y \ne \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points of $X$, $U=X\setminus\{x\}$, and $V=X\setminus\{y\}$; since $X$ is $T_1$, $\{U,V\}$ is an open cover of $X$. Suppose that $\mathscr{R}$ is an open refinement of $\{U,V\}$.

- Show that $\mathscr{R}$ must have at least two elements.
- Use the connectedness of $X$ to show that $\mathscr{R}$ cannot be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Ok, $\mathcal B$ has at least two elements since every $B\in \mathcal B$ is either contained in $U$ or $V$; then it contains at least two elements since it cannot contain only $X$, since $X$ isn't contained in $U$ nor $V$. Now, what do you mean by $\mathcal B$ cannot be pairwise disjoint, do you mean there aren't $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal B$ s.t $B_!\cap B_2 =\emptyset$? if there were such open refinement then since it covers $X$ the union of the open sets in $\mathcal B$ are $X$, which is a contradiction to connectedness of $X$.

Comment: Isn't a $T_1$ space a space that separates two distinct points by open nbhds that don't contain the other point?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: A collection of sets is pairwise disjoint if every pair of sets from the collection has empty intersection. And the point is that if $\mathscr{R}$ were pairwise disjoint, we could pick $R\in\mathscr{R}$ and let $W$ be the union of the other members of $\mathscr{R}$, and $\{R,W\}$ would be a disconnection of $X$. \\ Your definition of $T_1$ is correct. However, you should know (or prove, if you’ve not seen it before), that a space $X$ is $T_1$ if and only if $\{x\}$ is closed for each $x\in X$.