# Infinite connected Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

If $X$ is a connected Hausdorff space and $X$ has more than one point, then is $X$ infinite?

It’s well known that if $X$ is a connected metric space then the answer is in the affirmative. The proof is number 1 here:

[https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~claude/530mtm.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eclaude/530mtm.pdf)

So since every metric space is Hausdorff, the answer to the question is clearly yes.
What would a non-metric proof look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A $T1$ connected space having more than one point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476082/a-t1-connected-space-having-more-than-one-point)

Comment: Well this question is bit general. Wait nvm the question you referenced is more general. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is a finite Hausdorff space then every singleton set is closed which implies that every subset is closed. Hence $X =\{x\} \cup (X \setminus \{x\})$ gives  a disconnection of $X$ unless $X$ has only one point. So either $X$ has only one point or  it is infinite.